# Convert C# Web App in C# library -- problem with Response Object

Tags: c#

I try to convert a part of a C# Web App to make a C# Library.

I used a Response object, but this one is no more recognized in the C# library.

Here some code:

```
// Create a CAPTCHA image using the text stored.
CaptchaImage ci = new CaptchaImage(textCaptcha, 200, 50, "Century Schoolbook");

// Change the response headers to output a JPEG image.
this.Response.Clear();
this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

// Write the image to the response stream in JPEG format.
ci.Image.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// Dispose of the CAPTCHA image object.
ci.Dispose();
```

How to use the Response object, or change it with something better?
Thx

Comment: I can't seriously believe that you really mean to ask this. Do you mean you are trying to shift part of it into a C# _library_ project?

Comment: Why do you want a captcha in a "regular" C# app?

Comment: Yes! a C# library, sorry! Post modify! I will use the dll file in an other project reference to include the Captcha.

Comment: Should this question be retitled to reflect the change made to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place web code in a C# library, but it only makes sense for some cases. You can use [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx).Response (so that it's static, and doesn't refer to the Response instance on a page) and call methods like "Clear" on that, but this doesn't mean anything to a non-web application that references the library. If you're creating a library to be used *by* web applications, this is probably fine.

You might try something like this:

```
HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

// Create a CAPTCHA image using the text stored.
CaptchaImage ci = new CaptchaImage(textCaptcha, 200, 50, "Century Schoolbook");

// Change the response headers to output a JPEG image.
currentContext.Response.Clear();
currentContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

// Write the image to the response stream in JPEG format.
ci.Image.Save(currentContext.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// Dispose of the CAPTCHA image object.
ci.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2):

The response object represent the stream that you are sending to the client.  In a desktop application there is no such concept you have no stream to send the client since your program is the client.  In your above example you are writing a captchaImage to the stream this image would be displayed on the clients browser. If that is your only intent you can use an [picturebox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) control to display the image.  If you just need to save the image you can write an image to a file stream in the same manner you wrote it to the response stream.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious. Personally I think the OP means to ask about shifting parts of his app into a library, not an application.

Comment: I didn't know what he was asking.  Except I have worked with people that have never written a desktop app and have asked me similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some other output stream/storage for your image. E.g. you can store it in file or in database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) objects to perform these functions within a C# winforms application (an assumption).

Comment: -1: it makes zero sense to use web response/request classes in a desktop application.

Comment: @x0n- that actually depends on the needs of the application. His question isn't entirely clear about exactly what he is trying to do, let alone what he actually needs. So I offered up documentation on how to use web requests from within the code behind.